# Understanding pthreads a little more in C

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, simultaneous

So I only very recently heard about these pthreads and my understanding of them is very limited so far but I just wanted to know if it would be able to do what I want before I get real into learning about them.

I have written a program that generates two output pulses from a micro-controller which happen with different frequencies, periods and duty cycles. At the moment the functions to output the pulses are happening in a loop and it works well because the timings I am using are multiples of each other so stopping one while not interrupting the other is not too much hassle.

However I want it be a lot more dynamic so I can change the duty cycles or periods easily without having to make some complicated loop specific for those timings... Below shows a quick sketch of what I am trying to achieve and I hope you can understand it...

[image]

So basically my question is, is something like this possible with pthreads in C, ie do they run simultaneously so one could be pulsing on and off while the one is waiting for a delay to finish?

If not is there anything that I could use for this instead?

Comment: What is max pulse rate and how much jitter can you afford?

Comment: Threads can only run simultaneously if you have more than one core/processor. For a single core threads can only run in serial, not in parallel. Using pthreads doesn't magically allow a single processor to run multiple sequences of instructions at the same time. However, if one thread is waiting (i.e. not actually running anything) then another thread can run, but there will be overhead to context switch between threads when a waiting thread needs to wake up and pulse.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not worth using threads for such functionality on a uC.  The cost of extra stacks etc. for such limited operations is not worth it, tempting it might be from a simplicity POV.

A hardware timer, interrupt and a delta-queue of events is probably the best you could do.